# WTForm custom inline validator

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I want to have an inline validator for duplicated username and email. however, it only works when I first define is as a function and put it in the list of validator.
The following is my codes

**Here is the flask**

```
from project import app, db
from project.forms import Reg_form
from project.models import User
from flask import render_template, flash, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_login import login_required

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    form = Reg_form()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
            new_user = User(email = form.email.data,
                            username = form.username.data,
                            password = form.password.data)
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Thanks for registering, you may login now.')
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('register.html', form = form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Here is the forms**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, SubmitField, PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import data_required, email, equal_to, length, ValidationError
from project.models import User
def check_email(self, email):
        if User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('Email has been registered')

def check_username(self, username):
        if User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('Username has been registered')

class Reg_form(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[data_required(), email(), check_email], render_kw={"placeholder": "your@email.com"})
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[data_required(), check_username], render_kw={"placeholder": "Your username"})
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[data_required(), equal_to('confirm_pw', message='Password must match with the confirmed password.')], render_kw={"placeholder": "Your password"})
    confirm_pw = PasswordField('Confirm password', validators=[data_required()], render_kw={"placeholder": "Confirm your password"})
    submit = SubmitField('Register.')
```

**Here is what I want but does not work**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, IntegerField, SubmitField, PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import data_required, email, equal_to, length, ValidationError
from project.models import User

class Reg_form(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[data_required(), email()], render_kw={"placeholder": "your@email.com"})
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[data_required()], render_kw={"placeholder": "Your username"})
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[data_required(), equal_to('confirm_pw', message='Password must match with the confirmed password.')], render_kw={"placeholder": "Your password"})
    confirm_pw = PasswordField('Confirm password', validators=[data_required()], render_kw={"placeholder": "Confirm your password"})
    submit = SubmitField('Register.')
    def check_email(self, email):
            if User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first():
                raise ValidationError('Email has been registered')

    def check_username(self, username):
            if User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first():
                raise ValidationError('Username has been registered')
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because custom validators must start with `validate_`. I've actually found this quite hard to pinpoint in the docs (e.g. it's not explicitly mentioned [here](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validators.html) where I think it deserves a mention) but you can see it in [the implementation](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/23f730a9cfca478f01fda2b38fde17ad56e9a83d/src/wtforms/form.py#L289):

```
def validate(self):
    """
    Validates the form by calling `validate` on each field, passing any
    extra `Form.validate_<fieldname>` validators to the field validator.
    """
    extra = {}
    for name in self._fields:
        inline = getattr(self.__class__, "validate_%s" % name, None)
        if inline is not None:
            extra[name] = [inline]

    return super(Form, self).validate(extra)
```

So, you need to change `check_email` to `validate_email` etc.

Comment: It is an excellent answer. Sadly I do not have enough reputation to upvote for you :(